# why my program takes 100% of my RAM on stress testing (72 GB)

Tags: windows, asp.net-core, ram, stress

I have a solution based on .net core 2.0 and it reaches 100% RAM (72 GB) in an hour on stress testing.
I need to know if there is a any work around to force garbage collector without changing the code?
Any environment level changes/third party tools.

### Environment:

OS: Windows server 2012
RAM: 72 GB

Comment: Using 100% of RAM is not a problem by itself. How is your throughput after that hour?

Comment: It is 80 in total but 45% of throughput is coming from a cache.Actual/financial transaction throughput is around 45.

Comment: @HenkHolterman it consumes whatever CPU or RAM you give it. Even if I double the RAM and CPU, it will consume 100% in same amount of time and not much difference in throughput